# How to count characters InputTextArea using @bind-Value in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor

I have this base component:

```
public TicketDetail AddedTicketDetail { get; set; } = new TicketDetail();
```

and I use it in the razor file like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                    <InputTextArea @bind-Value="AddedTicketDetail.Description" @bind-Value:event="oninput" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="attachment-label">Characters: @AddedTicketDetail.Description.Length</span>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => AddedTicketDetail.Description)" />
                </div>
```

But this is not counting the characters. And as soon as I move out of the text area, it goes directly to my validation. Is there a way that I can use InputTextArea and @bind-Value to get the count of the characters without resorting to just using `textarea` and the simple @bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force the "build in" `InputTextArea` or `InputText` to bind on `oninput`. But you can inherit the `InputTextArea`:

```
@inherits InputTextArea

<textarea @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValue"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString)" />
```

([source](https://www.meziantou.net/validating-an-input-on-keypress-instead-of-on-change-in-blazor.htm))

And then use it in your code without the `@bind-Value:event="oninput"`

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <InputTextAreaOnInput @bind-Value="AddedTicketDetail.Description"  class="form-control" />
 <span class="attachment-label">Characters: @AddedTicketDetail.Description.Length</span>
 <ValidationMessage For="@(() => AddedTicketDetail.Description)" />
</div>
```